# IllegalStateException: TimeSkipEvent may only be triggered synchronously

Tags: java, bukkit

I get this message when trying to change the world time asynchronously

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: TimeSkipEvent may only be triggered synchronously.
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:595) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-253]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftWorld.setFullTime(CraftWorld.java:948) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-253]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftWorld.setTime(CraftWorld.java:936) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-253]
        at ru.lmpx.lmpxserverkit.handlers.NightSkipHandler.lambda$onPlayerSleep$0(NightSkipHandler.java:29) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:99) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-253]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:54) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-253]
        at com.destroystokyo.paper.ServerSchedulerReportingWrapper.run(ServerSchedulerReportingWrapper.java:22) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-253]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
```

```
@EventHandler
    public void onPlayerSleep(PlayerBedEnterEvent e) {
        if (!(plugin.getConfig().getBoolean("skipNight.enable"))) return;
        if (e.getBedEnterResult().equals(PlayerBedEnterEvent.BedEnterResult.OK)) {
            if (plugin.getConfig().getBoolean("skipNight.instantSkip")) {
                Bukkit.getWorld("world").setTime(0);
                Bukkit.getWorld("world").setStorm(false);
            } else {
                Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(plugin, () -> {
                    while (Bukkit.getWorld("world").getTime() < 24000) {
                        Bukkit.getWorld("world").setTime(Bukkit.getWorld("world").getTime() + 10);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

What needs to be changed so that the asynchronous thread changes time without an IllegalStateException error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is explicit, you cannot call a synchronous method asynchronously. This is to ensure that [thread safety](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-safety) is upheld. To fix your code, you would need to change out `runTaskAsynchronously()` with [`runTask()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html#runTask(org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin)), however, with your current code, this would freeze the main thread.

A better solution is to use the [`runTaskTimer()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html#runTaskTimer(org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin,long,long)) method. You can create a new class that extends [BukkitRunnable](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html). The below code is untested but it should be close to what you need:

```java
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

public class BedTask extends BukkitRunnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        World world = Bukkit.getWorld("world");
        if(world.getTime() >= 24000){
            this.cancel();
            return;
        }
        world.setTime(world.getTime() + 10);
    }
}
```

And you could then execute it like:

```java
int sleepWaitPeriod = 10;
new BedTask().runTaskTimer(plugin, 0L, sleepWaitPeriod * 20);
```